# Doxygen: How to fix the TreeView separator bar so it extends to the bottom of the page

Tags: doxygen

When using `TREEVIEW` with doxygen, the bar separating the box on the left stops part of the way down the page.

[image: Example screenshot of the bar stopping about 90% of the way down the page]

Is there a way to fix this so that the separator always extends to the bottom of the page?

In my Doxyfile, I don't see any options that can control this. It also appears that the doxygen homepage has the same issue (although it is less obvious due to the color scheme). Is this just a bug in doxygen?

[image: A second example screenshot of the bar stopping about 90% of the way down the page, this time from the Doxygen homepage.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look to me like a bug in doxygen, when people use very small letters or have a very large screen / canvas.
In the generated `html/navtree.css` we have the block:

```
.ui-resizable-e {
  background-image:url("splitbar.png");
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  cursor:ew-resize;
  height:100%;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width:6px;
}
```

and I think this would be better when the: `background-repeat:no-repeat;` is set to `background-repeat:repeat;`,

so:

```
.ui-resizable-e {
  background-image:url("splitbar.png");
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  cursor:ew-resize;
  height:100%;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width:6px;
}
```

As a solution / workaround, for your own generated output, one can set the `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` with an extra stylesheet overruling the default stylesheet setting so e.g. `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = my_navtree.css` and place in the `my_navtree.css` the following code:

```
.ui-resizable-e {
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

I've just pushed a proposed patch for the master repository of doxygen (pull request 6455, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6455): "Truncated split bar in HTML output between treeview and normal text area", this pull request has been integrated into the development master of doxygen.